Playwright scripts are not getting executed on Azure DevOps
My Playwright scripts are running fine in local. However same scripts are failing in Azure DevOps pipeline with the below error:

Error: Playwright Test did not expect test.describe() to be called here.
Most common reasons include:

You are calling test.describe() in a configuration file.
You are calling test.describe() in a file that is imported by the configuration file.
You have two different versions of @playwright/test. This usually happens
when one of the dependencies in your package.json depends on @playwright/test.


Error i am getting:

Azure pipeline yml file:

I have made sure

I have only 1 playwright version
all commands and locations in yml file are correct
scripts are running fine in local


Please share details--the code as a [mcve], commands you're running, package.json, environment. Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Thanks.

From your error message, I notice that the test file is under the path: TestCase-10459-StandarReport/tests/dashboard/alarm_count_quick_lists.
In your YAML sample, you are executing the playwright command with the file path: tests/dashboard/alarm_count_quick_lists/xxx.js The default working directory of the script task is s folder.
So the cause of the issue can be that the command execution path has issues.
Test the similar YAML sample, I can reproduce the same issue:

To solve this issue, you need to set the correct workingDirectory in the npx playwright test task.
For example:
- script: npx playwright test alarm_count_list.spec.js
  displayName: 'Run Playwright test '
  workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestCase-10459-StandarReport/tests/dashboard/alarm_count_quick_lists
  env:
    CI: 'true'

In this case, npx playwright test command will find the js file in the correct path.

Thanks @Kevin Lu-MSFT this resolved my issue :)

Hello Kevin, now when i am running the tests, chromium is getting installed in a different folder and playwright is looking for it in a different folder.
Error i am getting: Error: browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /home/vsts/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1124/chrome-linux/chrome
Actually chrome got installed at: /home/vsts/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1129/chrome-linux/chrome
Any quick fix on this please?

@user26942972 From the error message, it seems that your project needs to use old version of the chromium and pipeline has installed the latest one. You can try to run npx playwright@1.45.1 install before Install Playwright browsers task to install the required chromium 1124 version. If it still not work, I suggest that you can create a new ticket to share more logs about the issue. This will be helpful to solve the issue.

Awesome Kevin, this too worked, thanks much !!
